# Is HMM Smoothing more computationally complex than HMM filtering?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, bayesian, hidden-markov-models, stochastic-filtering

Given a sequence of observations $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$, of some lates sequence of Markovian states $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$:

HMM filtering computes $p(x_k|y_1,\dots,y_k) \\$

HMM smoothing computes $p(x_k|y_1,\dots,y_n). \\$

HMM filtering uses the forward algorithm and HMM smoothing uses forward-backward algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#Filtering). Is forward-backward algorithm more complex than forward algorithm? What are the complexities?

Comment: Forward algorithm (FA) and forward backward algorithm (FBA) have the same complexity $\Theta(nm^2)$, where $m$ is the number of hidden states (see Wikipedia, e.g.). To the best of my knowledge, usually FBA requires twice as many computations as FA (forward and backwards algorithm require the same amount of computations). However, edge probabilities (if they need to be computed) only need to be computed once.